# Periodically refresh side input from database

Tags: apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I have a use case to refresh side input periodically. I've tried different possible ways, but no luck.

```
    final PCollectionView<Map<String, String>> userMap = pipeline
            // This is trick for emitting a single long element in every N seconds.
            .apply("update-very-n-seconds",
                    GenerateSequence.from(0).withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(120L)))
            // Applying it to Fixed Window
            .apply("assign-to-fixed-window", Window
                    .<Long>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(120)))
            )
            .apply(Sum.longsGlobally().withoutDefaults())
            .apply("read-user-data", new ReadUserData(userDsFn))
            .apply("global-window",
                    Window.<KV<String, String>>into(new GlobalWindows())
                            .triggering(Repeatedly.forever(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                            .discardingFiredPanes())
            // Caching results as Map.
            .apply("cache-results-as-map", View.<String, String>asMap());
```

ReadUserData.java

```
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.KvCoder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.coders.StringUtf8Coder;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.io.jdbc.JdbcIO;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.DoFn;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.PTransform;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.ParDo;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.transforms.SerializableFunction;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV;
import org.apache.beam.sdk.values.PCollection;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class ReadUserData extends PTransform<PCollection<Long>, PCollection<KV<String, String>>> {

    private SerializableFunction<Void, DataSource> dataSourceProviderFn;

    public ReadUserData(SerializableFunction<Void, DataSource> dataSourceProviderFn) {
        this.dataSourceProviderFn = dataSourceProviderFn;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<KV<String, String>> expand(PCollection<Long> input) {

        return input.apply("Read User table.", JdbcIO.<Long, KV<String, String>>readAll().withDataSourceProviderFn(dataSourceProviderFn)
                .withQuery("select id, concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) from users")
                .withCoder(KvCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), StringUtf8Coder.of()))
                .withRowMapper(
                        (JdbcIO.RowMapper<KV<String, String>>) rs -> KV.of(rs.getString(1), rs.getString(2))));
    }

}
```

Here is the error.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.ExecutionGraph       [] - Combine.globally(SumLong)/Combine.perKey(SumLong) -> Combine.globally(SumLong)/Values/Values/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous) -> read-user-data/Read User table./ParDo(Read)/ParMultiDo(Read) -> read-user-data/Read User table./JdbcIO.Reparallelize/Consume/ParDo(Anonymous)/ParMultiDo(Anonymous) -> (read-user-data/Read User table./JdbcIO.Reparallelize/View.AsIterable/MapElements/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous), read-user-data/Read User table./JdbcIO.Reparallelize/View.AsIterable/View.CreatePCollectionView/Combine.globally(Concatenate)/WithKeys/AddKeys/Map/ParMultiDo(Anonymous) -> ToKeyedWorkItem) (2/2) (984107a1613dc7e05ddf37750140a5fb) switched from RUNNING to FAILED on contact-pipeline-taskmanager-1-1 @ ip-192-168-183-51.us-west-2.compute.internal (dataPort=46571).
org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.ExceptionInChainedOperatorException: Could not forward element to next operator
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException.wrap(UserCodeException.java:39) ~[?:?]
```

The side input patterns recommend using `ParDo` to read external data. I've not found any working example to refresh side input from the database.

Please let me know if there is a way to refresh side input from database.

Thanks,
Suresh